# Create user friendly alias for a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, url, mapping, alias, administration

I have a test Sharepoint server running on a Windows 7 machine.  The url is http://liu-t500-01 and i want to create a user friendly alias http://temp for it.  i have added

127.0.0.1    temp

to my hosts file (an A/host entry) and i have also created an alternate access mapping in Central Administration

http://liu-t500-01  Default     http://liu-t500-01
http://temp             Intranet    http://temp

However when i try http://temp in the browser the sharepoint site does not come up. This is probably a simple problem but has me scratching my head...what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the IIS binding only will cause errors. You need to modify the alternate access mappings in SharePoint. There are tons of good articles our there that tell what to do in detail.

Here is just one: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/Video/ff679917

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a host header in IIS

- In IIS click on your site
- choose the **Bindings** action
- Click **Add**
- In the **Host Name** field enter "temp"
- click **OK**